# Where Is Opera Plug-ins Database?

Tags: windows, flash, opera

In Opera 12 for the PC, you can see the plug-in used for .SWF files by clicking Tools/Preferences/Downloads/{find .SWF}/Edit...

The path & file ("npswf32.dll") pointed to by Opera exists on my hard drive, but I cannot change that filename or path within Opera. Does anyone know whether I could manually edit a file where Opera stores this information? I'd like to be able to change Flash plug-ins with a quick restart of Opera versus an entire re-install of Flash.

Comment: They are stored in your %appdata%\opera and %localappdata%\opera. I don't know where exactly, but you'll find it there.

Comment: Thank you.  I was confused: The pertinent data is in a file named "handlers.ini".  This file (and for that matter the entire Opera folder) is missing for some reason on that machine, whereas it is present on my machine.  I will try reinstalling Opera and edit "handlers.ini" from there.

Comment: You can move the profiles folder. A file from the opera folder will point to where the profile is. I believe its called profile.ini or something.

Comment: Interesting.  That might explain why, after reinstallation, "handlers.ini" could not be found.  I'll check that out, thank you.

Comment: I could not find anything that relates to an Opera "profile". The re-installation didn't help.  The Opera folder under my %appdata% is actually empty.  The whole issue is quite odd.  But thank you for your help.  I will fiddle with it some more and post here if I find a solution.  However, I am also going to install the Vivaldi browser and see whether that gets me what I want.